# Renaming classes Jackson XML serialization in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, deserialization, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I found cool Jackson XML library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.10</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

It works with no extra configurations:

```
val xmlMapper = XmlMapper()
xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(CustomIntegration)
```

where `CustomIntegration` is a data class

```
data class CustomIntegration(val name: String)
```

For an **input** `CustomeIntegration("Integration A")`, an *output* will be

```
<CustomIntegration>
    <name>
        Integrartion A
    </name>
</CustomIntegration>
```

The question is how I can change `CustomIntegration` to `integration` when deserializing to XML? There are numbers of use-cases I want to address:

- Single implementation for any class, so `CoolIntegration`, `AwesomeIntegration` all will convert into tag `integration`
- I cannot just rename class `CustomIntegration` into `integration` because it is almost like `SOAP:envelope` into SOAP integrations, so in the same tag can be with different content
- Ideally, I want to write as little code as possible, to simplify the maintenance of it

The only solution I found so far is to write custom deserializers but this wouldn't fully address all non-functional requirements I am trying to meet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634080/jackson-xml-and-json-root-element).

In order to change the root element name in XML, you need to put `@JsonRootName(value = "integration")` annotation.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "integration")
data class CustomIntegration(val name: String)
```

**Output** will be:

```
<integration>
    <name>
        Integrartion A
    </name>
</integration>
```